# how detecting if combo selection is selected for first time

Tags: java, swt, listener

My question is simple: I have a swt combo and I must do some things if the combo was selected for first time, and do other things if it was selected other times than first. Sorry but I´m newbie and I don´t know how to do that. The listener is in inner class:

```
combo_agrupacion1.addSelectionListener(new GroupListener());

    class GroupListener extends SelectionAdapter {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent evento) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*You will not find a built-in solution for that.* The best you can do is:

First create a variable, something like:

```
private boolean wasSelectedAlready = false;
```

Then in your `widgetSelected()` function start with an `if`:

```
if (!wasSelectedAlready) {
   wasSelectedAlready = true; //your function will not execute it
                              //is main body ever again
   do anything else you ever wanted to do in this function
}
```

Comment: thanks Gergely! I thought that option, using a "flag" like we say, but I thought there was a built-in solution. I tried this anyway! Thanks again!